# PowerShell Receive-Job Output To Variable Or File But Not Screen

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the job details without outputting the data to the screen. However, regardless of what option I try, the job logs always get sent to the console. Any ideas on how to save the logs in a variable or file without outputting that data to console?

```
Receive-Job -Id $id -Keep -ErrorAction Continue > C:\Temp\Transcript-$VM.txt

$info = Receive-Job -Id $id -Keep -ErrorAction Continue
```

Comment: The job must have a `Write-Host` or `Out-Host` statement in the script block. You should remove that if so. You could also set the `$InformationPreference` variable to `'Ignore'` in the scriptblock if you are on PowerShell v5 or later, but it may have unintended consequences. The `-InformationAction 'Ignore'` on `Write-Host` does the same thing with a specific command and doesn't impact the environment settings.

Comment: The job does have Write-Host commands in it and they can be seen when running the Receive-Job command as it outputs this info to the screen.

Comment: Also I tried all the options for $InformationPreference ('Ignore') is not one of them see below link, but it still displays content to the screen, or stops the script completely.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6

Comment: What is your powershell version?

Comment: PSVersion: 5.1.18362.145

Comment: Also tried the following as a add on to the command, not using the $variable method but the Receive-Job command still displays output to the screen.

-InformationAction Ignore

Comment: You can see the action preference values on your system running `[enum]::getnames('System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference')`. If `Ignore` is there, you can use it. The online documentation is obviously not updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that your job uses `Write-Host` output and that you're running Windows PowerShell v5.1.

**In order to *also* capture `Write-Host` output** - which in v5+ is sent to the ***information stream* (stream number `6`)** - **use [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) `6>&1`**:

```
# Capture both success output and information-stream output
# (Write-Host) output in $info.
$info = Receive-Job -Id $id -Keep -ErrorAction Continue 6>&1
```

Unfortunately, due to a [known *bug*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9585), you'll still get console output *as well* (bug is still present in PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5).

**Catch-all redirection `*>&1`** normally routes *all* streams through the success output stream.

**Unfortunately, due to the bug linked to above, the following streams *cannot* be captured or redirected at all when using *background jobs* or *remoting***:

- verbose messages (`4`)
- debug messages (`5`)

---

The only **workaround** is to capture the streams *inside the job* and save them to a file *from there*, and then access the files from the caller later.
Of course, this requires that you have control over how the jobs are created.

A simplified example:

```
# Redirect all output streams *inside* the job to a file...
Start-Job { 
 & { 
   # The job's commands go here.
   # Note that for any *verbose* output to be captured,
   # verbose output must explicitly turned on, such as with
   # the -Verbose common parameter here.
   # You can also set $VerbosePreference = 'Continue', which 
   # cmdlets (including advanced functions/scripts) will honor.
   'success'; write-verbose -Verbose 'verbose'; write-host 'host' 
 } *> $HOME/out.txt 
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove
# ... then read the resulting file.
Get-Content $HOME/out.txt
```

Note that I've used a *full* path as the redirection target, because, unfortunately, in v6- versions of PowerShell script blocks executed in background jobs do *not* inherit the caller's current location. This will change in PowerShell Core v7.0.

Answer (score -1):

Try placing it in a pipeline, and see if that works:

```
Receive-Job -Id $id -Keep -ErrorAction Continue | Set-Content 'C:\Temp\Transcript-$VM.txt'
```

Comment: Output in the file is the below. Also still shows the logs on screen.

Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceGroupDeployment
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSComputeLongRunningOperation
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSComputeLongRunningOperation

Comment: [This bug report](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9585) explains why that won't help.

Comment: Also, `>` _does_ involve a pipeline, behind the scenes; it is like implicit use of `| Out-File`, so what you're suggesting fundamentally couldn't be expected to make a difference.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought he was attempting to hide the actual output of the job object and send to file, not gather the output of the DataStream of the job.